# Как добавить в лог файл событие о доступе к ноде и вложенным в нее?

Tags: java, jcr, aem, cq5

Использую АЕМ.

В **JCR** есть нода **/data/*** (в ней есть вложенные ноды)

Необходимо вести запись в лог-файл при попытке доступа к самой ноде и к ее дочерним элементам.

Eсли из какого-то места идёт запрос на чтение любой ноды под /data - нужно логировать этот запрос.

Как это можно сделать с помощью java?

Comment: Напишите, чем логируете. Что значит "при попытке доступа" ?

Comment: @Dred, логирем при помощи slf4j....  "при попытке доступа" - имеется ввиду чтение/запись/любое изменение...